# Conditional formatting with icon sets- copy to entire row

Tags: excel, reference

I have 3 columns with percentages.

I would like to put an up or down arrow in the same cell as each percentage depending on the previous percentage.

ex: H10 = 54, L10 = 55, P10 = 50

I'd like `L10` to read `55` with an up arrow and `P10` to read `50` with a down arrow. Then I want to copy this formula down to the 500th rows for columns `L` and `P`.

I was able to create this for 1 row (`H10`, `L10` and `P10`), but when I tried to copy it down to the other rows, it continued to reference the first row (`H10`, `L10` and `P10`), .  I tried to remove the "$" absolute reference and got an error message saying I cannot use relative references.  How can I copy this formatting all the way down.

The fields I am using  (row `H`, row `L`, row `P`):

[image]

Comment: What's your `applied to` range? Also instead of using an entire column try narrowing it to say `$L$10:$L$100` (assuming it's 100 rows of data).

Comment: Hi Bruce, I edited my original post.  my applied to cells are columns L and P. I'd like to apply this to column L (by column L looking at column H) and I'd like to also apply it to column P (By column P looking at column L).  I am not so tech savvy so not certain I answered your questions appropriately.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible because excel does not allow relative references for icon sets in conditional formatting, for whatever reason. The only work-around I can think of would be to add another column where you use a formula to determine whether the cell will display an up-arrow character or a down-arrow character. In my experience, Excel is notoriously bad at automating anything dealing with images or icons.

Comment: thank you Peter, I took this advice and played with the display of the rows so it appears as if the additional row is a part of the row with the values (L, H, P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way I can think of to get a relative reference while only using what "looks like" an absolute reference.

```
= $A1
```

returns the same thing as:

```
= OFFSET($A$1,ROW()-ROW($A$1),0)
```

Notice that the formula above uses only absolute references but effectively returns a relative reference.

Try using this method to see if it will work in your case.

Comment: Thank you for trying, I got an error saying the following: "The value you entered is not a valid number, date or time"

Comment: One more try: `= INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN($A$1)))` will also return the same thing as `= $A1`. If this doesn't work, I'm out of ideas for now.

Comment: it put it in quotes and treated the formula like a string rather than a formula.  lol.  thank you for trying.

Comment: Sorry, I guess there isn't a way around it for this type of conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to get around this:

I added another cell and calculated the difference between the rows, then set the formula to evaluate if the difference was negative or positive (greater than or less than 0), if it was positive there is an up arrow and if negative there is a down arrow.  I made the new row small enough that only the arrow shows and the number doesn't, and I don't have borders on the two rows (the one with the number and the one with the formula) so it looks like the additional row is actually part of the row that has the true value (not the calculation).